# What is difference between protected and private derivation in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between private, public and protected inheritance in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c)

What is difference between deriving as protected or private in c++? i am not able to figure out, since both seem to restrict base class member access from derived class object

Comment: To be frank, both are a bit of a waste of space. In over 25 years of professional C++ programming, I've never used either in anger.

Comment: @unapersson: I've never used protected inheritance, but I've used private inheritance before.  A class inherits publicly from a read-only interface, and privately from a read-write interface.  It can then pass itself to functions expecting the read-write interface, but any other class or function must use the read-only interface.  Saves declaring a friend.  Used it in an implementation of the Builder pattern.

Comment: @Daniel For me, composition will always win over private inheritance, as it reduces coupling. But YMMV. Protected inheritance has always been a bolt on - I seem to remember that it was added sometime around cfront 2.x simply because somebody thought public/protected/private access should be mirrored in the inheritance specifiers. But maybe my memory is playing tricks.

Comment: @unapersson:  Private inheritance is occasionally useful for deriving from things like boost::noncopyable.  That is, when you're trying to hide an interface (copy ctor, etc.) rather than expose one.

Comment: @unapersson: I have posted a [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2268/composition-or-private-inheritance-for-implementing-builder) to codereview.  I'm interested in your comments and critique of my technique.

Comment: I'd like to point out that an important use of private inheritance is to enable the empty base optimization. Apart from this I feel quite comfortable never using it.

Comment: @Luc: I agree (for Policy Based Design), one more reason to feel strongly against that non-zero size for all objects :/

Answer (score 9):

Let's consider a code example showing what would be allowed (or not) using different levels of inheritance:

```
 class BaseClass {};

 void freeStandingFunction(BaseClass* b);

 class DerivedProtected : protected BaseClass
 {
     DerivedProtected()
     {
         freeStandingFunction(this); // Allowed
     }
 };
```

`DerivedProtected` can pass itself to `freeStandingFunction` because it knows it derives from `BaseClass`.

```
 void freeStandingFunctionUsingDerivedProtected()
 {
     DerivedProtected nonFriendOfProtected;
     freeStandingFunction(&nonFriendOfProtected); // NOT Allowed!
 }
```

A non-friend (class, function, whatever) cannot pass a `DerivedProtected` to `freeStandingFunction`, because the inheritance is protected, so not visible outside derived classes.  Same goes for private inheritance.

```
 class DerivedFromDerivedProtected : public DerivedProtected
 {
     DerivedFromDerivedProtected()
     {
         freeStandingFunction(this); // Allowed
     }
 };
```

A class derived from `DerivedProtected` can tell that it inherits from `BaseClass`, so can pass itself to `freeStandingFunction`.

```
 class DerivedPrivate : private BaseClass
 {
      DerivedPrivate()
      {
          freeStandingFunction(this); // Allowed
      }
 };
```

The `DerivedPrivate` class itself knows that it derives from `BaseClass`, so can pass itself to `freeStandingFunction`.

```
class DerivedFromDerivedPrivate : public DerivedPrivate
{
     DerivedFromDerivedPrivate()
     {
          freeStandingFunction(this); // NOT allowed!
     }
};
```

Finally, a non-friend class further down the inheritance hierarchy cannot see that `DerivedPrivate` inherits from `BaseClass`, so cannot pass itself to `freeStandingFunction`.

Comment: So there *are* "useful" applications of protected / private inheritence. Thanks for the nice examples.

Answer (score 3):

Use this matrix (taken from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Classes/Inheritance)) to decide the visibility of inherited members:

```
inheritance\member  |     private     |   protected   |   public
--------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------
private             |  inaccessible   |    private    |  private
protected           |  inaccessible   |    protected  |  protected
public              |  inaccessible   |    protected  |  public
--------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------
```

Example 1:

```
class A { protected: int a; }
class B : private A {};       // 'a' is private inside B
```

Example 2:

```
class A { public: int a; }
class B : protected A {};     // 'a' is protected inside B
```

Example 3:

```
class A { private: int a; }
class B : public A {};        // 'a' is inaccessible outside of A
```

Answer (score 1):

`private` allows only the class it is declared in to access it
`protected` allows that class and derived/sub classes to access as if it were private

Answer (score 1):

I had added a very detailed explanation about `Inheritance` & `Access Specifiers` in [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/cannot-access-private-member-of-a-class-error-in-c/5448004#5448004). It explains all the types of Inheritance and how access specifiers work with each of them. Do have a look.
Hth :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `protected` inheritance extends further down the inheritance hierarchy than does `private` inheritance. See [the C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.5) for details.