# what happens for virtual function that is non-public inherited by subclass?

Tags: c++

I have seen this question http://www.careercup.com/question?id=384062

```
class Base {
public :
    virtual void method () = 0;
private :
    int n;
};

void Base::method() { n = 1;}

class D1 : Base {};

class D2 : public D1 {
    int i;
    void method() {i = 2;}
};
```

It passed the compiler of vs2008 and g++ 4.4.3

Here is my understanding of above code, please correct me if I am wrong

**S1**> D1 has inherited variable Base::n but it cannot access it.

**S2**> D1 has inherited the function Base::method but it doesn't call/modify this inherited function in the above implementation.

**S3**> D2::method is not an overridden version of D1::method

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public/%5d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`D1` has inherited variable `Base::n` but it cannot access it.***
**Correct.**
Private members of a class are never accessible from anywhere except the members of the same class.

---

***`D1` has inherited the function `Base::method` but it doesn't call/modify this inherited function in the above implementation.***
**Correct, but conditonally, Read below for why:**

`D1` inherits the `Base::method` but it is not calling/invoking it because you did'nt add any statement to do so. But it can call it.
Pure virtual functions can have a body and they can be called by drived class members just like any other member function.

```
class D1 : Base 
{
    public:
        void doSomething()
        {
            Base::method();
        }

};
```

Note that in your Base class `n` is private so the only way to access it is through member function of Base & since only `method()` can do so, You can do it through it.

Note that presence of **atleast one** pure virtual function makes an class **Abstract Class**, And one cannot create objects of an Abstract class. Any class deriving from an Abstract class **must override ALL** the pure virtual functions of the Base class or else the derived class becomes an Abstract class as well.

Based on above rule,
In your case both `Base` and `D1` are Abstract classes.

---

***`D2::method` is not an overridden version of `D1::method`***
**Incorrect**
Though `method()` is not acessible to the ouside world through instance of class `D1`, it is still very much a part of it. Access control dictates access rights not presence or absence of members.
So, Yes, `D2::method` is an **overriden** version of `D1::method` and it **hides** it as well, just that in this case, `D1::method` was not acccessible in the first place

Comment: Can you please explain the third statement: "Though `method()` is not accessible inside the class `D1`". May I know why is this not accessible inside the class `D1`. Since `D1` privately inherits from class `Base`, `method()` is now a private member of class `D1`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Purninma: That is a typo, I meant `method()` is not accessible to outside world through instance of `D1`. And as to your other query on my comment, As you yourself rightly said, `method() is now a private member of class D1`, so by redefining it, You are overriding and hiding the Base class version of `method`.

Comment: @Als, the calling of `Base::method()` can be simply written as method() since `method()` is a member of `D1`.

Comment: @q0987: `method()` is a virtual function and hence it will be called through dynamic dispatch, Whether `Base::method()` will be called or `D2::method()`, will depend upon the type of object being pointer by the `Base pointer`, So, if you want to specifically call base class method irrespective of the actual object being pointed to is `Base` or `D1` then you will have to explicitly specify it as `Base::method()`.

Answer (score 2):

S2 and S3 are wrong.

D1's methods can call it's Base::method(), but other code can't as Base part of D1 is private.

Base::method() is overridden by D2. If you somehow convert (new D2) to (Base*) and call Base::method, the i=2 code will run.

Considering access control, if you have pointer to Base*, external code can use ->method() because it's public, and if you have pointer to D2*, ->method() can't be called because it's private, even if it's the same object and the same method.

Also, despite your (n=1) implementation for Base::method() it and its class remain abstract.

Answer (score 1):

In this case both Base and D1 classes are abstract classes which cannot be instantiated.

S1 - yes

S2 - Yes D1 has inherited the function. Can you please clarify your question.

S3 - No. D2::method is the override you have provided for the D2 class.

Edit:
I just noticed the private inheritance of `D1` from `Base` class. In that case, S1 and S2 still hold good.

Updated: S3: D2::method is both overriding and hiding the base class method.

Comment: @Purnima: `D2::method` is overriding the `Base` class method `Base::method()` and it hides the Base class version of it, The method though not accessible in `D2` is still very much a part of it.

Comment: @Als: I think what you said would be true if it were public inheritance between classes `Base` and `D1`.

Comment: @Purnima: It is true even if it is `private inheritance`. Access specifers dicate access rights of members which are part of the class, they do not control the presence or absence of members inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

S1: Correct

S2: Correct

S3: Correct, more clearly D2::method hides D1::method

Answer (score 0):

S1 - Correct

S2 - Sorry I'm not very clear what you meant. In `D1` or subclasses you can define `method()` to override it in `Base` but cannot call it. And, `D1*` cannot be converted to `Base*` because of private inheritance.

S3 - Incorrect. Once you declare a member function as `virtual` in the base class, it will keep `virtual` in subclasses even you leave out `virtual`. So in your case, `method()` in `D2` is a overridden version of `D1::method()` and `Base::method()`.