# C++, please explain Classes to a Python user?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++, Thanks to this article I find many similarity between C++ and Python and Javascript: http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/python2Cpp.html

But I can't understand C++ Classes at all, they looks like Javascript prototypes, but not that easy.

For example:

```
//CLxLogMessage defined in header

class myLOG: public CLxLogMessage{
  public:
    virtual const char *    GetFormat (){
            return "Wavefront Object";
    }

    void    Error (const std::string &msg){
            CLxLogMessage::Error (msg.c_str ());
    }

    void    Info (const std::string &msg){
            CLxLogMessage::Info (msg.c_str ());
    }

 private:
    std::string     authoringTool;
};
```

Question: What is this Public/Private stuff at all!?

Edit: To be honest, I more enjoy C++ than Python, because I can learn truth meaning of everything, not simple automated commands, for example I preferred to use "int X" rather than "X" alone.

Thanks

Comment: You really need a good book to start with.

Comment: @Ndv: Explaining "C++ classes, public/private stuff" is a topic for a whole book. Too broad for this Q&A site.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes) might be a good start and you could follow up with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public/%5d).

Comment: Doesn't Python have classes and object-orientation, too? These should be quite similar (although it has been some time since I messed with Python, and it was only a short time). If not then shame on me, but otherwise you should rather first learn python before trying to learn C++ from a python-to-C++ learning resource.

Comment: @Christian: Yes, Python has classes as well. Although many of the features of C++'s class system are left out in favour of dynamic typing and otherwise not putting much restrictions onto people's code - members are not declares, there are no access specifiers except programmer's conventions (hence also no `friend` and only one kind of inheritance), everything is always virtual, etc.

Comment: @delnan Ok, then his question was at least poorly worded, as he should know what a class is and how it works and is only unclear of the private/public stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myLOG` is the name of the class. It inherits (look it up<sup>2</sup>) from `CLxLogMessage` and has the functions `GetFormat` (which is `virtual` and can be overridden by subclasses and called through base class pointers, look it up<sup>2</sup>), `Error`, and `Info`. It has the data member `authoringTool` which is a string.

The `public` and `private` stuff is access specifiers. Something in the `private` section can only be used by the class's member functions, and stuff in the `public` section can be used by anybody. There is another type of section called `protected` which means that only a class and its subclasses can access it, but nobody else<sup>1</sup>.

If you start adding stuff to a class without setting an access level first, it defaults to `private`.

You can have as many `public`, `private`, and `protected` sections as you want, in any order.

You need these different protection levels because you don't want other people messing with your data when you don't know about it. For example, if you had a class representing fractions, you wouldn't want someone to change the denominator to a 0 right under your nose. They'd have to go through a setter function which would check that the new value was valid before setting the denominator to it. That's just a trivial example though. The fact that Python does not have these is a shortcoming in the language's design.

All your questions would be answered if you had read a C++ book. There is no easy way out with C++. If you try to take one, you'll end up being a horrible C++ programmer.

<sup>1</sup> You can let somebody else access `private` and `protected` members by declaring them as `friend`s (look it up<sup>2</sup>).

<sup>2</sup> Sorry for saying "look it up" so much, but it's too much information for me to put here. You'll have to find a good resource for these kinds of things.

Comment: The last `private` in your 2nd paragraph should be `protected` I think.

Comment: +1, but I think the third `private` is meant to be `protected`

Comment: @Ndv whoops had a typo, updated. The other section that I was talking about is called `protected`, not `private`. Thanks Iccarrasco and Mat, I spotted the error and fixed it.

Comment: @Ndv do you know Python classes? It's basically the same but with more features.

Comment: @Ndv which parts of "more features" are you not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Even though there's no way to give a comprehensive answer or anything near that, maybe think about it like this: classes are **types**. Consider this:

```
int n;
```

Here "int" is the name of a type, and "x" is a variable of type "int". There are basic types in C++, like "int", "char", "double". Now we can also make new, compound types from old types:

```
struct Foo
{
  int n;
  char c;
  double d;
};
```

This defines a new type called "Foo", and `Foo x;` makes a new variable of that type. Now we can add some magic to the type "Foo":

```
class Foo
{
  int n;
  double d;

public:
  Foo() : n(20), d(0.5) { }   // "constructor"
};
```

The keywords `struct` and `class` almost mean the same thing, so we still have a compound type that has two member variables, `n` and `d`. However, this type also has a member *function*, and this one gets called every time you create a new Foo object. So when you say, `Foo x;`, then this variable's member value `x.n` will be set to 20 and `x.d` will be set to 0.5.

So that's that in a nutshell: Classes are types with built-in magic. And you are the magician.

Comment: Baby steps. It isn't that hard, there's just a lot of it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The private and public is to do with data encapsulation, it means you can change the implementation of the class without affecting how it is used. I suggest reading up on some of the theory of object orientation.

Comment: @Ndv if you want easy and quick, C++ is not for you.

Comment: Have you tried looking for tutorials? The internet is full of them.

Comment: @Ndv: If you really knew the Javascript and Python object orientation approaches, you would not ask this question.