# Pointer to base class and private inheritance

Tags: c++

The following simple example will produce a compiler error, since I accidently use private inheritance:

*main.cpp:21: error: ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘B’*

```
class A
{


};

class B : /*ups forgot that -> public*/ A
{


};

int main(int , char *[])
{
    A* test = new B;

    return 0;
}
```

Could you help me and explain what exactly is inaccessible in the base class and why it is needed in the conversion from `B*` to `A*`?

Comment: [What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public/%5d) is a good read for you.

Comment: also this link maybe useful http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Private inheritance means that for everyone except B (and B's friends), B is not derived from A.

Comment: Could you explain that in terms of `constructors` on function level? What functions are inaccessible due to the private inheritance?

Comment: @Ronald: The entire class is inaccessible, including all constructors, and any other members. Nothing is accessible.

Comment: But why can I create a `class B` then at all if `class A` is totally inaccessible? Sorry I am confused :-)

Comment: @Ronald McBean: Because `A::A()` is called (implicitly) from `B::B()`, and all B's members _can_ access A.

Comment: Because when you construct B, B's constructor calls A's constructor, which is fine.  B can access all public members of A, including the (compiler generated in this case) constructor.

Comment: @Ronald: The private base class is accessible by all of `B`'s members and friends, including the constructors, so there's no problem with instantiating `B`. It is not accessible anywhere else, which is why the pointer conversion fails.

Comment: @Ronald, you were confused by wrong answers that were removed. @Jan's answer is correct: "external" code doesn't know B inherits from A, so you can't use an `A*` to point on a `B*`. The construction is not the problem.

Comment: It's actually quite like private members and functions: B can access them, others can not.

Comment: Thank you all, your answer and all comments helped a lot!

Comment: But a static (or C style) cast is apparently possible?

Answer (score 8):

> Could you help me and explain what exactly is inaccessible in the base class and why it is needed in the conversion from B* to A*?

Ouside of `B` and the friends of `B`, the simple fact that `B` *is an* `A` is not visible. This is not hiding a member variable or member function, but hiding the relationship itself. That is why from `main` you cannot bind the result of `new B` with a pointer to `A`, because as far as `main` is concerned, `B` is not an `A` (in the same way that you could not do `A * p = new unrelated;`)

As to why it is needed, the answer it exactly the same: because without access to the relationship, the compiler does not know (well, it knows, but will not tell you) how to obtain a pointer to the `A` subject inside `B`, because as far as it can see within that context there is no relationship between `A` and `B` at all.

Comment: Thanks David, very good explanation. I think I got it now :-)

Answer (score 3):

The ***conversion*** from `B*` to `A*` is inaccessible, because ***the base-class subobject is private***. When you convert `B*` to `A*`, you ***return the pointer to the base-class subobject***. The latter must be accessible for the conversion to be accessible. In any function that is friend to `B` the ***conversion*** becomes accessible. By the way, you can always access the conversion by an explicit cast.

```
A* p = (A*)(new B);
```

Note that in some cases just accessible conversion is required, but in some cases it is required that `A` be a public (stronger than accessible) base of `B`. For example, when you try to catch an exception of type `B` with `catch(A&)` - it is required that `A` be a ***public*** base class of `B`.

Comment: The explicit cast you mentioned, is it functionally the same as a `reinterpret_cast`? Meaning, from a compiler point of view, you convert two totally unrelated types?

Comment: @Ronald: To be perfectly hones, I am not sure. In the standard, the examples use C-style cast without mentioning which cast it is. You can try by writing static_cast. If it works, then it is static_cast, otherwise it's reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 1):

Since the ***reference*** or ***pointer*** of Base class can not point to object of inherited class, does it mean that **protected and private inheritance is nothing to do with polymorphism?**

Answer (score 0):

Since B is inherited from A, the default constructor of A would be called before the constructor of B. But because it is private and not inherited to B, you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Public/private inheritance is **equivalent** to public/private member variable.

The result of the conversion is **a reference to the base class subobject of the derived class object**.

I think the accessibility means the accessibility of the base class subobject of the derived class object.For client,only if we ues public inheritance，the base class subobject is accessible.For the member function of derived class,no matter we use public/protected/privaye inheritance, the base class subobject is accessible.

```
class A{

};

class B: private  A{
private:
    int* m_pb;
public:
    B(){m_pb=new int(10)};
    void func()
    {
        A* pa= new B;      //OK
        int *pmb = m_pb;   //OK 
    }

};
int main()
{
    B* pb = new B;
    A* pa= pb;             // inaccessible
    int *pmb = pb->m_pb;   // inaccessible 
}
```

OK.I means that public/private inheritance is equivalent to public/private member variable.

reference:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ratdevz/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.tpf.toolkit.compilers.doc%2Fref%2Flangref_os390%2Fcbclr21011.htm