# assignment of an protected struct member to a friend?

Tags: c++, friend, access-rights

I have a classes that contains data in form of MyObjects like class A.
I wish to Monitor the data in the MyObject objects. So I created a IMonitorable class and
derived all my storage classes that contains the MyObjects from IMonitorable. Add added the IMonitorable class as a friend to my monitoring class.

```
class IMonitorable
{}        

class a : public IMonitorable
{
protected:
   struct myData
   {
      MyObject a;
      MyObject b;
      ...
   } data;
}

class Monitor
{
public:
   friend IMonitorable;
   AddData(a& stroage);
   AddObject(MyObject& obj);

}
```

This worked fine while I had one storage class with a known myData struct. I called

```
AddData(InstanceOfA);
```

and added MyObject a,b,.. to my monitoring mechanism.

Now I have several storage classes and I don't want to write an AddData method for all storage classes. I thought of having a AddObject method to be able to have a single point suitable for all storage classes.

```
AddObject(InstanceOfA.data.a);
AddObject(InstanceOfA.data.b);
...
```

But if I call this somewhere in my code gcc throws the error data.a is protected, what is right.

Is there a way to add a reference or a pointer of the protected MyObject to the Monitor without the knowledge of the structure of the storage class?

Comment: Friends are not inherited in C++.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371087/c-friend-inheritance

Comment: The question is quite confusing. Take the time to check the code, and identify the meaning of some of the terms you use, like *storage*. Make sure to identify what object is trying to access what other object, what the error is and where it happens.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `struct myData` as protected. `friend IMonitorable` declare `IMonitorable` as friend class that means that `IMonitorable` has acces to private members of `Monitor` class. To access private members from `Monitor` use `getter` function:

```
class a : public IMonitorable
{
public:
   const myData* const getData()const
   {
      return &data;
   }
   myData* getData()
   {
      return &data;
   }
protected:
   struct myData
   {
      MyObject a;
      MyObject b;
      ...
   } data;
}
```

Use it:

```
AddObject(InstanceOfA.getData()->a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see exactly what you are doing, and you confuse things by using `a` both as a class and then a member of myData.

But I think the issue is that that friendship is not reciprocated.

You have made `IMonitorable` a `friend` of `Monitor`, but that does not make `Monitor` a `friend` of `IMonitorable`, and incidentally even if you did make it a friend of `IMonitorable` it wouldn't get access to protected members of `a` which derives from it.