# How to propagate friend for derived classes

Tags: c++, friend

I want to have a class hierarchy and be able to create objects from it only inside a Factory.

Example:

```
class Base
{
    protected:
        Base(){};
        virtual void Init(){};

    friend class Factory;
};

class SomeClass : public Base
{
    public://I want protected here! Now it's possible to call new SomeClass from anywhere!
        SomeClass(){};
        void Init(){};
};

class Factory
{
    public:
        template<class T>
        T* Get()
        {
            T* obj = new T();
            obj->Init();

            return obj;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Factory factory;
    SomeClass *obj = factory.Get<SomeClass>();
}
```

My problem is that I want to be able to make objects only from Factory, but I don't want to declare `friend class Factory` in every class derived from Base.

Is there any way to propagate friend in derived classes? Is there any other way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: You cannot inherit `friend`ship. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844129/friend-class-with-inheritance/13844421#13844421

Comment: Be aware that `protected` is only slightly more restrictive than `public`. Anybody would be able to inherit from `SomeClass` and provide a way into its `protected` members.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, it's deliberately impossibile.

Is an issue by encapsulation.

Suppose to have a class "PswClass" that manage any password, that is cascade friend with other class: if I inherit from PswClass:

```
 class Myclass : public PswClass {
     .......
 }
```

In this way I can, maybe, have access to field that it would be private.

Answer (score 4):

Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive, as described here: [friend class with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844129/friend-class-with-inheritance/13844421#13844421).

After a little experimentation, and making some use of this hack [How to setup a global container (C++03)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899866/how-to-setup-a-global-container-c03/13899981#13899981), I think I have found a way give the "factory" unique rights to create the objects.

Here's a quick and dirty code. (Scroll towards the bottom to see the hack.)

```
class Object {};

class Factory {
public:
    // factory is a singleton
    // make the constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator private.
    static Factory* Instance() {
        static Factory instance;
        return &instance;
    }

    public: typedef Object* (*CreateObjectCallback)(); 
    private: typedef std::map<int, CreateObjectCallback> CallbackMap; 

public: 
    // Derived classes should use this to register their "create" methods.
    // returns false if registration fails
    bool RegisterObject(int Id, CreateObjectCallback CreateFn) {
        return callbacks_.insert(CallbackMap::value_type(Id, createFn)).second; 
    }

    // as name suggests, creates object of the given Id type
    Object* CreateObject(int Id) {
        CallbackMap::const_iterator i = callbacks_.find(Id); 
        if (i == callbacks_.end()) { 
            throw std::exception(); 
        } 
        // Invoke the creation function 
        return (i->second)(); 
    }

    private: CallbackMap callbacks_; 
};

class Foo : public Object {
    private: Foo() { cout << "foo" << endl; }
    private: static Object* CreateFoo() { return new Foo(); }


public:
    static void RegisterFoo() {
        Factory::Instance()->RegisterObject(0, Foo::CreateFoo);     
    }
};

class Bar : public Object {
    private: Bar() { cout << "bar" << endl; }
    private: static Object* CreateBar() { return new Bar(); }

public:
    static void RegisterBar() {
        Factory::Instance()->RegisterObject(1, Bar::CreateBar);     
    }
};

// use the comma operator hack to register the create methods
int foodummy = (Foo::RegisterFoo(), 0);
int bardummy = (Bar::RegisterBar(), 0);

int main() {
    Factory::Instance()->CreateObject(0); // create foo object
    Factory::Instance()->CreateObject(1); // create bar object
}
```

Comment: I read the book and indeed is a great one:) I wanted to make all the derived classes easy to write and also to restrict object creation. With this metod anybody can call CreateX without any restriction and also "register all" function must be changed everytime a new type is added. I prefer static registering:)

Comment: Ah, sorry I think I overlooked that part about noone else should create it. Let me think about that some more.

Comment: @Felics Hang on, I found an ugly-looking (but "working") workaround, which also addresses your requirement to prohibit constructing the objects from elsewhere. Let me post the code in a bit.

Comment: @Felics Well, on second thoughts, maybe not. You still need to create a dummy per class, but it address your requirement, and I think this is safer than `friend`ing the `Factory`. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You can make int RegisterX() and you don't need the comma hack:) Also you can make a class that register the type in constructor and just declare a variable of that "registering type". It is more clean:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21277/discussion-between-felics-and-ap)

Comment: Your father's friend is NOT your friend :)

Answer (score 2):

As others already said, friendship is not inheritable.

this looks like a good candidate of "Abstract Factory" pattern.

assume "SomeClass"es derived from base are used polymorphically.
declare a abstract factory base, which creates Base objects.
derive each concrete factory from base, override the base creation method...

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern for examples

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to inherit `friend` declaration from base class. However, if you make `Base` constructor `private`, instances of derived classes won't be possible to create without `Factory` help.

Comment: If the Base constructor were private, derived class constructors couldn't exist at all -- unless the base class friends the derived class(es).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. This is done to protect encapsulation. See this post: [Why does C++ not allow inherited friendship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561648/why-does-c-not-allow-inherited-friendship)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, another idea that came out of the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21277/discussion-between-felics-and-ap) between OP and me, which works with only one use of `friend` as the OP wanted. Of course, this is not a universal solution, but it may be useful in some cases.

Below code is a minimal one which shows the essential ideas. This needs to be "integrated" into the rest of the `Factory` code.

```
class Factory;

class Top { // dummy class accessible only to Factory
private:
    Top() {}
friend class Factory;
};

class Base {
public:    
    // force all derived classes to accept a Top* during construction
    Base(Top* top) {}  
};

class One : public Base {
public:    
    One(Top* top) : Base(top) {}
};

class Factory {
    Factory() {
        Top top;  // only Factory can create a Top object
        One one(&top);  // the same pointer could be reused for other objects
    }
};
```

Comment: Interesting idea, which doesn't work. You can't create a `Top` object, but you can create a pointer, as in: `Top * t; One o(t);` and it compiles just fine. If you were to change the pointer to a reference, it would also still work: `Top *t; One o(*t);` compiles just fine (and since `Base` would ignore `t`, the fact that it's undefined works perfectly even though the `*t` is _undefined behavior_).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. As others have said friendship is not inherited.

An alternative is to make all class hierarchy constructors protected and add the factory function/class as friend to all the classes you're interested in.