# C++. member function cannot be called. error : "foo is private"

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

class MyClass { 

  void Foo(const int par);  }; 


void MyClass::Foo(const int par) { } 

main()  {    MyClass A;    A.Foo(1);  }
```

Anyone can help me? What is wrong with my code? This is the error I get when compiling with gcc:

```
error: ‘void MyClass::Foo(int)’ is private
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class members and class member functions are by default private, meaning they can only be accesed by methods of the same class and friends.

```
class MyClass {  

  // members declared here will be private

public: 

  // members declared here will be public
  void Foo(const int par); 

private:

  // private

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods are `private` by default. Use

`public: void Foo(const int par);`

Comment: Methods are only private by default if they belong to a `class`. For a `struct` (which can also have methods in C++), the default access level is `public`.