# inherited function inaccessable in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a small program in Visual C++ 2010.

This is code of the base class:

```
class BaseInfo {

private:
    std::map <std::string, std::string> info;
    std::vector<std::string> extra_info_key;
public:
    uint get_id ();
    //Other function is hidden
};

uint BaseInfo::get_id () {
    return (uint)atoi ((info["ID"]).c_str());
}
```

Then I make a derived class, which is announced as:

```
class test:BaseInfo {
public:
    void f();
};

void test::f (test& inf) {
    cout<<inf.get_id()<<endl;
}
```

But I got an error:

> function "BaseInfo::get_id is inaccessible.

I am confused, it seems all is in the c++ rules.

Comment: may I suggest using a few more spaces for legibility

Comment: [What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public/%5d) Should be a good read.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using private inheritance, that's why.
Change:

```
class test : BaseInfo
```

to:

```
class test : public BaseInfo
```

For more info about public, protected and private inheritance, look [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html)

Comment: interesting that structs inherit publicly by default, classes privately.

Comment: Same with members, in structs they are public by default, in classes - private.