# c++ inheritance syntax

Tags: c++, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)
>   [Difference between private, public and protected inheritance in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c)

To all you cpp experts,
In c++ inheritance,

```
class B : public A {
};
```

I am just curious why is the keyword public needed here? Does it mean something?

Comment: Please use google and the SO search bar before asking a question. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c), or if it doesn't explain it to your satisfaction, just search google about C++ inheritance.

Comment: I'm afraid you are not facing any problem here, so it'll probably get closed really soon. You should read the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to know what you should and shouldn't ask here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means `public` members in `A` are inherited by `B` and are also public from `B`.

The alternatives are:

- protected - public members from `A` are made protected in `B`, others are kept the same.
- private - all members from `A` are made private in `B`.

The rules don't apply to methods that are hidden or overriden.

Comment: What's the default if we omit it?

Comment: Default is public

Comment: default is private