# C++ : Restrict method access in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an object of class Message, which can be written and subsequently updated. As far as I can see, MessageUpdate IS-A MessageWrite:

```
class MessageWrite
{
  protected:
    void setVersion(int version_) {...}
    void setReceiveTime(int tmReceive_) {...}

    Message _msg;
};


class MessageUpdate:public MessageWrite
{
    //ONLY setVersionShould be accessible here, NOT setReceiveTime
};
```

Is there a combination of method access level and inheritance level that can help achieve this?

I know that MessageUpdate can be simply made base class, but there's the rub: it leads to diamond pattern in case i want to extend the message class. Consider:

```
class MessageUpdate {...};
class MessageWrite: public MessageUpdate {...};


//Now, while extending:
class AdminMessageUpdate:public MessageUpdate {...};
class AdminMessageWrite: public AdminMessageUpdate, public MessageWrite //DIAMOND Pattern!!
```

Where'e the gap in my understanding of inheritance? And is there any completely different way to achieve this logic without the multiple inheritance (as shown in latter code piece)?

Comment: Diamond pattern is OK as long as you are not afraid of [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21607/13140 for an example of using a virtual base class to ensure you don't get multiple copies of "MessageWrite" in your inheritance tree.  So you want ONLY MessageWrite to be able to call setReceiveTime()?

Comment: thanks dasblinkenlight, but i would prefer @Als 's method as it saves me the runtime cost of multiple inheritance as well

Comment: yes Ogre Psalm33. MessageUpdate objects and derivatives should NOT be able to call setReceiveTime() at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all members of `MessageWrite` are `protected`, you could just make `setReceiveTime()` `private` inside `MessageUpdate`, so classes inheriting from `MessageUpdate` would not be able to access it. But I still have some issues with your design, such as:

How is it that your design avoids the diamond? Wouldn't it equally lead to:

```
class MessageWrite {...};
class MessageUpdate: public MessageWrite {...};

//Now, while extending:
class AdminMessageWrite:public MessageWrite {...};
class AdminMessageUpdate: public AdminMessageWrite, public MessageUpdate //DIAMOND Pattern!!
```

Why do you think `MessageUpdate` IS-A `MessageWrite` when you later say it is not (by specifying that not all of `MessageWrite` applies to it)? If this code must not be valid:

```
MessageWrite& m = MessageUpdate();
m.setReceiveTime(); // Should this be valid?
```

then `MessageUpdate` IS-NOT-A `MessageWrite`. If my code should be valid, then there is no reason to avoid access to `setReceiveTime()` in `MessageUpdate`.

And you would probably be better off by creating a base class `AdminMessage` and then inheriting directly from it to avoid the diamond:

```
class MessageWrite {...};
class MessageUpdate: public MessageWrite {...};

//Now, while extending:
class AdminMessage {...};
class AdminMessageWrite: public MessageWrite, public AdminMessage {...};
class AdminMessageUpdate: public MessageUpdate, public AdminMessage {...}; // No diamond
```

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the method:

```
private:
void setReceiveTime(int tmReceive_);
```

with `private` access specifier in the Base class `MessageWrite`.

This answer of mine should be a good read:

**[What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5448004/452307)**

Comment: thanks, thats spot on. There's no way I can do this automatically? Have to rewrite all methods declarations?

Comment: @vid: You will have to do that manually. Also, access specifiers for class members are specified in class definition for method declarations.Note that Usually class methods are *declared* in header file and *defined* in the cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

If `MessageUpdate` is-a `MessageWrite`, then by definition, it has access to all of its protected and public members.

So, if there are members that you want publicly/protectedly-exposed in `MessageWrite` that you don't want exposed in `MessageUpdate`, then by the [*Liskov Substitution Principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_Substitution_Principle), `MessageUpdate` cannot be a `MessageWrite`.

Answer (score 0):

protected: inherited members can access.

private: inherited members can not access.

```
  protected:
    void setVersion(int version_) {...}
  private:
    void setReceiveTime(int tmReceive_) {...}
```