# Confusion with copy constructor and private member

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Test
{
             int num;
     public:
             Test(int x):num(x){}
             Test(const Test &rhs):num(rhs.num+1){}
};

int main()
{
      Test test(10);
      Test copy = test;
}
```

The `num` in the copy should be `11`, and my question is about inside the copy constructor, why can we access the private member `num` of `test` using `num` to initialize the `num` in the copy? What is confusing me is that if you type `cout<<test.num<<endl`, of course it's wrong because you are trying to access the private `num`, but if you pass the test by reference to the copy constructor, it works, can anybody tell me what is going on here?

Comment: , what confusing me is that if you type like "cout<<test.num<<endl", of course it's wrong because you want to access to the private num, but if you pass the test by reference to the copy constructor, it works, can anybody tell me whay's going on here, cause my English  is not very well   , i hope you guys can understand what i'm saying

Comment: Your english is not great, but suffices to get the point across. If you ask me, I would try to keep sentences shorter and avoid going over the same point multiple times. Also, when writing code in a question, surround it with back ticks \` to have it formatted as code and escaped (avoid the parser from interpreting `<test.num` as the beginning of an HTML tag

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I am trying to improve my English and learning everything

Comment: Good Read: [What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

Answer (score 6):

Private members are private to the class itself, not the instances of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Access limitations are per-class, not per-object.

"private" means -- can only be accessed from within the same class.

"protected" means -- can be accessed from within the same class, and can also be accessed from within derived-classes (in derived classes, protected non-static members can only be accessed through variables with derived class type).

"public" means -- can be accessed by anything.

The point of access limitations is to limit the region of code that has to be inspected in order to understand where the values are used, rather than to stop code from using the values.

Answer (score 1):

`private` doesn't mean private to the object instance.  It means private to that *class*.  An instance of a class `T` can access private members of other instances `T`.  Similarly, a static method in a class `T` can access private members of instances of `T`.

If `private` restricted access to only the individual instance, it would make objects non-copyable, since as you pointed out, the copy constructor would not be able to read data from the original instance.