# Class Data Encapsulation(private data) in operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, encapsulation

Below is the code

#### The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rational {
  int num;  // numerator
  int den;  // denominator
  friend istream& operator>> (istream & , Rational&);
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &  , const Rational&);
 public:
  Rational (int num = 0, int den = 1)
    :     num(num), den(den) {}
  void getUserInput() {
    cout << "num = ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "den = ";
    cin >> den;
  }
  Rational operator+(const Rational &);
};

Rational Rational::operator+ (const Rational& r) { //HERE 
  int n = num * r.den + den * r.num;
  int d = den * r.den;
  return Rational (n, d);
}

istream& operator>> (istream & is , Rational& r)
{
    is >> r.num >> r.den;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream & os , const Rational& r)
{
    os << r.num << " / " <<  r.den << endl;;
}
int main() {
  Rational r1, r2, r3;
  cout << "Input r1:\n";
  cin >> r1;
  cout << "Input r2:\n";
  cin >> r2;
  r3 = r1 + r2;
  cout << "r1 = " << r1;
  cout << "r2 = " << r2;
  cout << "r1 + r2 = " << r3;
  return 0;
}
```

The Question

The above code has a operator+ overloading , in the operator+ definition we can see the parameter `r` accessing the private data (r.num and r.den) . Why C++ allow the parameter to access private data outside of the class ? Is it some kind of a special case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access specifiers apply at the level of classes, not instances, so the `Rational` class can see private data members of any other  `Rational` instance. Since your `Rational operator+` is a member function, it has access to private data of it's `Rational` argument.

Note: the canonical approach is to define a member `operator +=`, and then use that to implement a non-member `operator+`

```
struct Foo
{
  int i;

  Foo& operator+=(const Foo& rhs) 
  { 
    i += rhs.i;
    return *this;
  }

};

Foo operator+(Foo lhs, const Foo& rhs)
{
  return lhs += rhs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Why C++ allow the parameter to access private data outside of the class ? Is it some kind of a special case?**

The rule with access specifiers is:
***"Access specifiers apply to per class and not per object"***
So, You can always access `private` members of a class object in member function of that class.

A copy constructor/copy assignment operator are commonly used examples of the rule though we do not notice it that often.

**[Online Sample](http://codepad.org/KG6mlA7i)**:

```
class Myclass
{
    int i;
    public:
       Myclass(){}
       Myclass(Myclass const &obj3)
       { 
            //Note i is private member but still accessible
            this->i = obj3.i;
       }
};

int main()
{
    Myclass obj;
    Myclass obj2(obj);
}
```

**Good Read:**
[What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

Comment: the friends are just annoying distractions here. OP is askinf about ``operator+``.

Answer (score 1):

`Rational::operator+` is a member function, so it has access to **all** members of **every** `Rational` object.

Coding tip: this kind of things is usually written in two parts: an `operator+=` that's a member, and an `operator+` that's not. Like this:

```
Rational& Rational::operator+=(const Rational& rhs) {
    num = num * rhs.den + den * rhs.num;
    den *= rhs.den;
    return *this;
}

Rational operator+(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs) {
    Rational result(lhs);
    result += rhs;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other posters have explained **how** the C++ access specifier work, no one has explained **why** they work in this way.

Increasing encapsulation is all about **minimizing the amount of code** which has access to your object internals (i.e. your data members), not the number of objects.  If the access specifiers limited access to the internals of other objects within the same class, this would *not* increase encapsulation.

Encapsulation is important because it means that changing implementation details will affect a minimal amount of code.  Increasing encapsulation increases the **maintainability** of code.  It is a build-time, not a runtime concept.

Answer (score 1):

The question reveals a misunderstanding:
"Why C++ allow the parameter to access private data outside of the class ?"

The method operator+ does belong to the class: it is declared within the class and in its implementation you'll see that the method is a member of the class by the prefix class_name::
So with operator+ there is no access if private members outside of the class.

The operators << and >> are a different case - these really do not belong to the class, since they are called by a stream object. That's why their implementation doesn't have the prefix Rational::.
To allow these operators the access to private data of the object they are declared to be friends of the class within the class declaration. By declaring functions or classes to be friend of my own class I show that I trust them not to tamper with the private data of my class.