# Violation of encapsulation?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class Data Encapsulation(private data) in operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390408/class-data-encapsulationprivate-data-in-operator-overloading)

Please look at this example.

```
class myClass {
    int a;
public :
    myClass () {
     this->a = 0;
  }

  myClass(int val) {
     this->a = val;
  }

  void add(myClass &obj2) {
     cout << "Result = " << this->a + obj2.a;
     obj2.a = 0;
  }

  void show() {
     cout << "a = " << this->a;
  }
};

int main() {
  myClass obj1(10), obj2(20);

  obj2.show(); //prints 20.
  obj1.add(obj2);
  obj2.show(); //prints 0. 

  return 0;
}
```

In the add() function, I am able to access the value of a private member of obj2 when I've actually called add() in the context of obj1. Isn't this a violation of encapsulation?

At first I was thinking that the compiler will throw me an error, but it didn't.

Comment: If you wanted the compiler to complain, why not declare `add` to take a `const` reference instead?

Answer (score 7):

No.

Encapsulation works at the *class* level, not at the instance level.

You can access private members of any instance of your class.
You can even access private members defined by your class through a reference to a class derived from your class.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a violation of encapsulation because you are accessing a member variable in a method both of which belong to the same class.  If obj2 was a reference of another class eg yourClass, then it would be a violation as you were accessing a private member of another class.