# How to grant access to a private method

Tags: c++, object, private

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

I am looking for some code or design pattern to grant access to a private method from another class (C++).

Let's say I have 1 class OBJ1 :

```
class OBJ1
{
  public:
    void method1();
    void method2();
}
```

And another class OBJ2, which instantiate OBJ1 :

```
class OBJ2
{
  public:
    void method3()
    {
       my_obj.method1();
    }
  private:
    OBJ1 my_obj;
}
```

Is there a way to access `OBJ2::my_obj.method2()` from other classes (this method only) ?

Comment: Can't you declare OBJ2::method3 a friend in the OBJ1 declaration?

Comment: @CoffeeonMars what would be the point? OBJ1 has only public members.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misread the access modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question: look at `method3`, which provides a way to call `method1` on `my_obj` via the enclosing class `OBJ2`. A similar forwarding method could be added to allow access to `method2`.

Comment: I'll try this, it should work. And you're right, I actually answered my own question... Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Accessing `method2` is possible, because it's public. Accessing the member `my_obj` can't be done directly because it's `private`. To grant other classes access to it, declare them as `friend` in `OBJ2`.

```
class OBJ2
{
  public:
    void method3()
    {
       my_obj.method1();
    }
  private:
    friend class X;
    OBJ1 my_obj;
}
```

Now, `X` can access `OBJ2::my_obj`.

Comment: But that opens up all operations on `my_obj`, not only `method2`.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker all operations on `my_obj` are already open... they're all public.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore `my_obj` is a private attribute of OBJ2, so `friend` does not solve my problem here. I want to know if there's a way to access `OBJ2::my_obj.method2()` (not `OBJ1::method2()`) **only**. :)

Comment: @Patouf it does. `X` can now access `OBJ2::my_obj`. Read my answer again.

Comment: His comment "(this method only)" implies that he doesn't want unlimited access to `my_obj` from X.  He only wants to be able to call `method2` from outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do this would be to provide a public passthrough function for this specific function, something like you did for `method3`:

```
class OBJ2 
{   
     public:
         void method3()     
         {
             my_obj.method1();
         }
         void method2()
         {
             my_obj.method2();
         }
     private:
         OBJ1 my_obj; 
}
```

This changes the syntax slightly -- you're calling the method against an OBJ2 instance rather than directly against the contained OBJ1 instance, but the effect will be what you asked for.

One other consideration here is that this type of idiom (public wrapper functions) gives unlimited external access to a single function of your contained member.  The other approach (friend declarations) gives a single external class access to the entirety of your private internals.  If what you want is to grant a single external class access to a single member, you might be better off combining these approaches using a proxy object or something of the sort.

Comment: +1 this is exactly what I was thinking but you said it first.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `public` method in `OBJ2` that calls `method2` on the `my_obj` member.

In this case `friend`ship won't help you because it would grant access to all of `my_obj`.

Answer (score 0):

From the design point of view, the language does not provide facilities to control per-member access, and while you can hack that in it is just going to make the code more convoluted, harder to maintain and to manage for the compiler (more complex code means harder to optimize code).

Some alternatives if that member is *really* different to the rest and objects accessing it shall not access the rest of the object would include defining an interface (polymorphic) and implementing that interface in `OBJ1`. Then you can hand a reference to that interface that has no other members available.

From a technical point of view there are multiple things that can be done, for example you can create an accessor function object that takes an `OBJ1` as parameter and calls the method. The functor would have to be a friend of `OBJ1` (assume all other members are private), `operator()` (or a named function that performs the dispatch, and make that private) and then befriend `OBJ2` from that intermediate dispatcher.