# How to make C++ inheritance preserve access specifer

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

How can I create a derived class in C++ which preserves the properties and methods' access specifier like this:

```
class Base
{
private:
    void base_private();

protected:
    void base_protected();

public:
    void base_public();
};

class A: [what type is appropriate here?] Base
{
public:
    void test() {
        base_protected(); // Ok
    }
};

class B: [what type is appropriate here?] A
{
public:
    void test() {
        base_protected(); // Ok
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a.base_public();        // Ok
    a.base_protected();     // Not Ok
    b.base_protected();     // Not Ok
    b.test();               // Ok

    return 0;
}
```

I mean `base_protected()` method is still protected in derived classes but `base_public()` is public.

Comment: That's what standard `public` inheritance does.

Comment: @BoPersson: So it's not `public` inheritance make all methods in  `protected` of base class to `public`?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: You need to read and understand the marked duplicate. It should answer all your questions.

Comment: @Binh - No, it sets a limit on the visibility. If you use protected inheritance, the inherited names will be protected or private. With private inheritance, everything will be private. With public inheritance, everything stays the way it is in the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets consider the availability of members of `Base`:

- `base_private` is not available to clients but available to `Base` itself
- `base_protected` is not available to clients but available to `Base` itself
- `base_public` is available to both clients and `Base`

Now, if you have `class A : public Base` (public inheritance), the availability of the members of `Base` will be:

- `base_private` is not available to clients and *not available* to `A` itself
- `base_protected` is not available to clients but available to `A` itself
- `base_public` is available to both clients and `A`

Now, what you're asking about is how to keep the same client interface for both classes, `Base` and `A`. If you look at the availability of the members for clients in the lists above, you will see that it is precisely the same for `Base` and `A`: `base_private` is not available; `base_protected` is not available; and `base_public` is available.

The only thing that has changed between `Base` and `A` is that `A` cannot access the members that are private to `Base`. That's the whole point of the `protected` access control - it gives derived classes access to their base classes members without making them available to clients.

So `public` inheritance is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

A derived class can access `public` and `protected` members of a base class, no matter whether you inherit `private`, `protected` or `public`.

When you inherit `private` all members of the base class are considered `private` for derived classes of `A`. Similar for `protected` inheritance, derived classes of `A` may access `protected` and `public` members of `Base`.

In both cases, `private` and `protected` inheritance, the members of `Base` are not accessible to the "public".

And now to answer your question, use `public` inheritance to preserve the access specifiers of the base class.