# member variable inheritance

Tags: c++

I have this code, note that two lines have been commented out

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
public:
    foo();
    int i;
};

class bar: foo {
public:
    bar();
    //int i;
};

foo::foo()
{
    i = 2;
}

bar::bar()
{
    i = 4;
}

int main()
{
    bar *b = new(bar);
    //std::cout << "bi = " << b->i << std::endl; /*line 28*/
    foo *f = (foo*) b;
    std::cout << "fi = " << f->i << std::endl;
}
```

With the two lines commented out, the code compiles and the output is

```
fi = 4
```

With the two lines uncommented, the code compiles and the output is

```
bi = 4

fi = 2
```

With only the declaration of i within class bar commented out the compilation fails

```
var.cc: In function ‘int main()’:

var.cc:6:7: error: ‘int foo::i’ is inaccessible

var.cc:28:30: error: within this context
```

I understand the first two cases but I do not understand this compilation error. Why is

the variable "i" accessible from within the bar constructor but not from a bar pointer?

Comment: Try inheriting from foo publicly `class bar : public foo`

Answer (score 3):

In private inheritance all members of base class become `private` members of the derived class. Note that for classes the default inheritance is `private` when you do not specify any.

Since `i` acts as an `private` member of `bar`, it can be accessed in `bar::bar()` but not from outside the member functions.

**Good Read:**

[What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

Comment: Ah, and inheritance is private by default. Making the inheritance public allows it to compile and the output is bi = 4 fi = 4. thanks.

Comment: @RichardJohnson: Do have a look at the link I provide in answer. It should explain you everything.

Comment: Thanks for providing that link, it was very informative. I may have to read it again (and maybe again) to get all the details.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you are using **private inheritance**.

For all `class`es, `private` is the default access modifier. This means that members and bases are `private` unless otherwise stated.

For a `struct` however, the default is `public`. Indeed, this is the only difference between a `class` and a `struct`.

Hence, when writing `class bar: foo`, this is equivalent to `class bar: private foo`.

To get rid of the issue, you need to do either `class bar: public foo` or `struct bar: foo`, both of which are equivalent in your example (since you have no members using the default access modifier).

Answer (score 0):

You should directly specify name scope of fields, if they has same name in different classes:

```
struct s1
{
  int i;
};

struct s2 : public s1
{
  int i;
};

int main()
{
  s2 v;

  v.s1::i = 1;
  v.s2::i = 2;

  std::cout << v.s1::i << v.s2::i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output will be 12