# access member in different classes

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes such as below:

```
class A : public C
{
void Init();
};

class B : public C
{
int a = 3;
};
```

How can i access the member of class B in class A?

```
class A::Init()
{
 class B. a  ???
}
```

Comment: There is only an `a` to access if you create an instance of `B`. Maybe you want it to be a static member instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

Comment: you should use getters and setters for class members to provide access.

Comment: What do you want to do by this code?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want a static member, which you can access without an object of type `B`?

```
class B : public C
{
public:
    static const int a = 3;
};
```

Now you can access it from anywhere (including your `A::Init` function) as `B::a`.

If that's not what you want, then please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

You must create an instance of the `class B` and declare the variable public

```
class B : public C
{
    public:
    int a=3;//Data member initializer is not allowed in Visual Studio 2012, only the newest GCC
};

void A::Init()
{
 B b;
 b.a= 0;
}
```

If you don't want to create an instance of `class B`, declare the variable static

```
class B : public C
{
public:
    static int a = 3;
};
```

And then access it like this:

```
void A::Init()
{
   B::a=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want access a "property" of class B as global, not a particular object then make variable static in this class

```
class B : public C
{
public:
    static const int a = 0;
};
```

and access it using `B::a`

---

alternatively:

```
class A{
public:
    void init(){
        static int a2 = 0;
        a1=a2;
    }
    int a(){return a1;}
private:
    static int a1;
};
int A::a1=0;
```

Comment: this looks great.. What if I have a function inside class B and I have a variable of a number, such as below :

class B : public C
{
    void Init();
};

class B::Init()
{
   int a = 4;
}

How do I access this variable a in 
void A::Init()
{
    ????
}

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add static function in your class. But I'm not sure if this what you 
are looking for.

```
class B: public C
{
public:
    static int GetA(void) {return a;}
private:
    static int a;
};
int B::a = 4;

class A: public C
{
public:
    void Init()
    {
    std::cout<<"Val of A "<<B::GetA()<<std::endl;
    }

private:
    int b;
};
```