# C++ Singleton usage: compiler complains about private constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I know that there is a million questions and answers about Singletons out there but I just can't seem to find the solution to this. So running the risk of negative votes, here's my problem:

I want to use this singleton implementation from Andrei Alexandrescu' Modern C++ Design:

header:

```
class Singleton
{
    static Singleton& Instance();
  private:
    Singleton(){};
    Singleton(const Singleton&){};
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&){};
    ~Singleton(){};
};
```

implementation:

```
#include "s.hh"

Singleton& Singleton::Instance()
{
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}
```

test:

```
#include "s.hh"

int main(void)
{
    Singleton& single = Singleton::Instance();
    return 0;
}
```

Now,

```
$g++ A.cc s.cc  && ./a.out 
In file included from A.cc:1:0:
s.hh: In function ‘int main()’:
s.hh:3:19: error: ‘static Singleton& Singleton::Instance()’ is private
 static Singleton& Instance();
               ^
A.cc:6:42: error: within this context
  Singleton& single = Singleton::Instance();
                                      ^
```

What is wrong with that? I am stuck...

Comment: Argh, that's what happens if you post a question before breakfast... In the original code I had the public specifier. I will post the "real" question in a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, a class' members are private. To access your singleton, you need to make `Singleton::Instance` public:

```
class Singleton
{
  // here!
  public:
    static Singleton& Instance();

  private:
    Singleton(){};
    Singleton(const Singleton&){};
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&){};
    ~Singleton(){};
};
```

Note that this is not the constructor (as you said in your title), it's the static member function that is supposed to return a reference to the singleton.

Comment: Where would be the implementation of Instance() function?
Implementing in .cpp it complains about private ctor, while implementing in .h - works.

Comment: It should be possible in the .cpp. Did you forget the Singleton:: ?

Answer (score 3):

Default access for a `class` is `private`, so you need to make the `Instance()` method explicitly `public`:

```
class Singleton
{
 public:
    static Singleton& Instance();
 private:
   // as before
....
};
```

Alternatively, you could use `struct`, whose default access specifiers are public:

```
struct Singleton
{
    static Singleton& Instance(); // public
  private:
    Singleton(){};
    Singleton(const Singleton&){};
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&){};
    ~Singleton(){};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The default access specifier for a class is `private`. Add the method under `public` access specifier.

```
public:
    static Singleton& Instance();
```

**Good Read:**
[What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

Answer (score 2):

```
class S
{
    public:
        static S& getInstance()
        {
            static S    instance; 

            return instance;
        }
    private:
            // other stuff here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Also don't make your other destructor private.

```
class Singleton
{
  // here!
  public:
    static Singleton& Instance();
    ~Singleton(){};

  private:
    Singleton(){};
    Singleton(const Singleton&){};
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&){};

};
```

Comment: *"don't make your other destructor private"*. Why?

Comment: @Kukuster because if the instance does get destroyed you want that memory cleaned up.

Comment: i see. So if destructor is private then it will not be called under the hood when the object gets collected automatically.