# Private Variable Inheritance

Tags: c++, variables, inheritance, private

I'm confused on how private variables are inherited and I'm getting errors telling my variable's are private when I try to use them in inherited classes.

A bare-bones example.

Let's say:

```
//dog.h
class dog
{
private:
    bool fluffy;
public:
    ...
};
```

And let's say:

```
//dog.cpp
#include "dog.h"
...
```

Now:

```
//shepard.h
#include "dog.h"
class shepard: public dog
{
private:
    ...
public:
    void groom();
};
```

And:

```
//shepard.cpp
#include "shepard.h"
void shepard::groom()
{
    fluffy = false;
}
```

If I try to use the groom function I get an error something like:

```
error: 'bool dog::fluffy' is private
```

What am I doing wrong?
Optional: What's the best way to design this solution in the future?

Comment: Subclasses don't get access to superclasses `private` variables - that's what makes them `private`. You need to make them `protected` to do what you want. +1 for deriving shepherd from dog, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important rule for inheritance is:

***Private members of a class are never accessible from anywhere except the members of the same class.***

Further in Private Inheritance:

> All Public members of the Base Class become Private Members of the Derived class &
>   All Protected members of the Base Class become Private Members of the Derived Class

**Good Read:**
[What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

Comment: @WillyGoat: Added a link of my previous answer for you to understand access specifiers & inheritance. Once you read it you can *understand* them better and decide for yourself what you need to use.